# Missing libz library on RedHat Install

Tags: plone

I am setting up a Linux RedHat Server and during installation i use this command

```
./install.sh --target=/home/admin/Plone --build-python zeo
```

which shows an error:

```
Unable to find libz library and headers. These are required to build Python.
Please use your system package or port manager to install libz dev.
(Debian/Ubuntu zlibg-dev)
Exiting now.
```

Comment: did you noted that the question title is totally unrelated?

Comment: Edited to fix title.

Comment: User also asked on [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273827/redhat-linux-server-plone-installation/273832). Problem seems to that a Red Hat subscription isn't registered on that system and/or that yum repositories are not configured.

Answer (score 3):

Check the dependencies and install them. In your case, I guess:

```
yum install zlib-devel
```

Normally you want to install the `-devel` packages of the required libs. Additionally you should have installed the "Development tools" package

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Search for packages with

```
yum search package-name
```

Or for binaries

```
yum whatprovides wantedBinary
```

Comment: when server shows following error:                                                            This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Comment: After installing showing following error:  Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h.
libssl and its development headers are required for Plone.
Please install your platform's openssl-dev package
and try again.
(If your system is using an SSL other than openssl or is
putting the libraries/headers in an unconventional place,
you may need to set CFLAGS/CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS environment variables
to specify the locations.)